# Application failed code sign verification log interpretation

Tags: xcode, signature, codesign

I've spent the last few hours trying to resolve this problem, and I'm not getting anywhere. At least I have a detailed report of the error, but I'm not sure how to interpret it.

```
Validate "/Users/brillig/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Troll_Calendar-aiiisgrydufzgqacxoigzflbhwzv/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Troll Calendar.app"
    cd "/Users/brillig/Desktop/Source Code/Troll Calendar"
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation "/Users/brillig/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Troll_Calendar-aiiisgrydufzgqacxoigzflbhwzv/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Troll Calendar.app"

warning: Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper:  (-19007)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)

warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
Executable=/Users/brillig/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Troll_Calendar-aiiisgrydufzgqacxoigzflbhwzv/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Troll Calendar.app/Troll Calendar
codesign_wrapper-4.1: using Apple CA for profile evaluation
/Users/brillig/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Troll_Calendar-aiiisgrydufzgqacxoigzflbhwzv/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Troll Calendar.app: valid on disk
/Users/brillig/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Troll_Calendar-aiiisgrydufzgqacxoigzflbhwzv/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Troll Calendar.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
test-requirement: code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)
codesign_wrapper-4.1: failed to execute codesign(1)
 - (null)
```

I'll handle the icon issue while I wait for a reply. The app runs just fine on my iPad when I build it for development. I thought I did everything I needed to in order to send it to the app store, but I can't get past this. If there were a checklist somewhere of everything needing to be done that would be great, but it seems like such a thing doesn't exist.

P.S. OK Maybe I have some progress. I changed from automatic profile matching to manually setting the profile, and not I get an error that indicates a mismatch.

```
Provisioning profile 'Troll Calendar App Store' specifies the Application Identifier 'com.domain.foo.bar' which doesn't match the current setting 'com.domain.Foo-Bar'.
```

So where are those two values coming from? I suppose I just need to change one of them to match the other. Which one would be simpler to modify? I think at the time these values needed to be entered, I was under the impression that it wasn't that important what the names were, so I didn't pay special attention to ensure consistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem in the organizer by selecting Target, Info, and changed the bundle identifier name to match the reserved identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new Distribution Certificate.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. I revoked my old distribution certificate (not really that old). Then I created a new once after uploading a new CSR. Then I created a new profile using that certificate. I did not create a new app id but used the existing one. Still no go.

Comment: I updated the question. Seems like I have to resolve a mismatch: "Provisioning profile 'Troll Calendar App Store' specifies the Application Identifier 'com.domain.foo.bar' which doesn't match the current setting 'com.domain.Foo-Bar'."

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. The problem for me was that I did the code signing in the PROJECT settings. I found out the there are the same settings for the product TARGET.

There I set the iPhone Distribution certificate for my Distribution configuration.